# How to compute eigenvectors and eigenvalues of complex matrices in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, eigenvalue, eigenvector, openmodelica

I am trying to use `Modelica` to compute the *eigenvalues* and *eigenvectors* for a complex matrix. Are there any libraries or built-in standard library functionality that I could leverage to assist me with this calculation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What properties does your complex matrix have? Is it symmetric?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Math Matrices](https://doc.modelica.org/om/Modelica.Math.Matrices.html) library it has various supported functions for matrices.

For example the `eigenValues(...)` method appears to be one that would be of interest to you:

`(eval,evec) = eigenValues(A)` - returns eigen values "eval" and eigen vectors "evec" for a real, nonsymmetric matrix A in a Real representation.

Straight from the [documentation](https://doc.modelica.org/om/Modelica.Math.Matrices.eigenValues.html) here is an example of using the `eigenValues()` method:

```
Example
  Real A[3,3] = [1,2,3;
                 3,4,5;
                 2,1,4];
  Real eval[3,2];
algorithm
  eval := Matrices.eigenValues(A);  // eval = [-0.618, 0;
                                    //          8.0  , 0;
                                    //          1.618, 0];
i.e., matrix A has the 3 real eigenvalues -0.618, 8, 1.618.
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I have tried the function, it is for computation of eigenvalues of real matrix, and it does not work for complex-number matrix

Comment: Hmm could you give it another try, according to the docs complex numbers are supported:  The first column of "eigenvalues" contains the real and the second column contains the imaginary part of the eigenvalues. If the i-th eigenvalue has no imaginary part, then eigenvectors[:,i] is the corresponding real eigenvector. If the i-th eigenvalue has an imaginary part, then eigenvalues[i+1,:] is the conjugate complex eigenvalue and eigenvectors[:,i] is the real and eigenvectors[:,i+1] is the imaginary part of the eigenvector of the i-th eigenvalue.

Comment: I read the docs such that the eigenvalue can be complex, not the input matrix.

Comment: I agree with your last comments, it does not support the input matrix as complex. what is the solution?